# Request a specific variable of JSON stream using bash/terminal

Tags: json, bash

I am working with a flutter web server testing. I writing a simple bash script to fetch some JSON data from API request. The API request dispatch following information as JSON response.

```
{

    "code_version":{
        "engine_name":"flutter_renderV1",
        "proxy":"10.1.1.1:1090",
        "test_rate":true,
        "test_density":"0.1",
        "mapping_eng":"flutter_default_mapper"

    },
    "developer_info":{
        "developerid":"30242",
        "context":true,
        "request_timestamp":"156122441"

    }

}
```

Once this received, I saved in to local file named `server_response{$id}.json`. I need to collect `test_density` value under `code_version` data frame. I used several `awk`, `sed` command to fetch data, unfortunatly I cannot get the exact output from my terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install powerful JSON querying processor like jq processor. you can can easily install from [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

once you install jq processor, try following command to extract the variable from JSON key value

suppose, your file named as `server_response_123.json`,

```
jq '.code_version.test_density' server_response_123.json
```

the output will be shown as,

```
"0.1"
```